# Prevent multiple firing of keydown events C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to allow the user to send his message when he press enter in the textbox.
I went to search and im using the sample codes below.

Now the problem is when i press enter, the event is triggered more than once like about 4-5 times.

Someone else suggested to use keyup. I have tried keyup, keydown and keypress. All have the same problem.
How do i prevent it from firing the event more than once?

```
private void tbxAnswer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbxAnswer.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbxAnswer_KeyUp);
    }

    private void tbxAnswer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Hello");

        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the `KeyUp` event handler multiple times (inside the `TextChanged` handler); therefore, when Enter is pressed, the handler executes multiple times.

What you want to do here is add the `KeyUp` handler just once, inside your form's constructor, just after the `InitializeComponent()` call:

```
public MyForm()
{
    // other code possibly here
    InitializeComponent();

    // and now add the event handler:
    tbxAnswer.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbxAnswer_KeyUp);
}

private void tbxAnswer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because every time you change the text, the tbxAnswer_TextChanged is called/ fired you assign an action to the keyup event; if the text is changed 4 times then you assigned the keyup event 4 times and it increases every time you change the text.
try this out:

```
tbxAnswer.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbxAnswer_KeyUp);
private void tbxAnswer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tbxAnswer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Hello");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
tbxAnswer.KeyUp -= tbxAnswer_KeyUp;
tbxAnswer.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbxAnswer_KeyUp);
```

Comment: im not totally sure here but what happens if you try to remove the event when its not added yet, as the case would be on the first key press....

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, whenever the text of the `TextBox` changes, another eventhandler is added to the `KeyUp` handler. You should only add event handlers once (for instance, just after creating the textbox).

Answer (score 0):

Sara and Jon have already provided the correct answer to your specific question. But if you want to go  further and get a better understanding of how and when to use any particular key handling event take a look at my article [Exploring Secrets of .NET Keystroke Handling](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/39607). I explain and diagram when and where each event is useful, plus provide a **KeystrokeSandbox** application that lets you actually watch what happens!